# Create grey transparent alert

Tags: ios, alert

I am looking for either the terminology or a reference on how to do this.

When you Successfully build a project on Xcode a nice, looking alert pops up. Like the one below: [image]

I have found only one other question on how to recreate this for Mac OS. I want the iOS version. I want to use this alert to show a count down for a timer. I have the count down fully functional but I'm not sure of a good way to display. I think this would be ideal for it.

Comment: Try [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is in objective-c. I am looking/wanting swift @robmayoff

Comment: Are you aware that you can use Objective-C classes from Swift? All of UIKit is written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the count down fully functional but I'm not sure of a good way to display

It's simply a view (UIView), with a transparent grey background color, rounded corners, and a light shadow. All of that can be readily be configured by straightforward view and layer properties in about three lines of code, and showing the view can be as simple as one line of code.